# Accessing a local system from outside

Tags: url, networking, ssh, ip, local-network

I have a local network at my home and have a system addressed at 192.168.2.2 in the local network. I want to access this local system from outside(of course I am aware of the Global IP) using both ssh and using URL. How can I do it? (Apache is installed in my system.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Note that your question is not related to programming, and it would be a better fit for our sister site, SuperUser.com . As for your question: you need to forward the ports 22 (ssh) and 80 (http) from your firewall to your computer; the way to do this depends on the firewall you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few posiblities.

First if you are targeting specific computer outside your home network and this computer has known IP you can initiate connection from your home PC to this computer using some program like Putty.

If you want to access your computer from anywhere at any time, than some kind of service should be used, google for "dynamic DNS free". Depending on your Internet connection you will make changes on your PC on your Router.

Answer (score 0):

To acces SSH from outside you need to portforward that port.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding for more information